# Sorting an array of objects based on an instance variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I'm trying to sort objects in an array based on its' date. For this, I have overridden the `sorted` method. I'm not allowed to use `key` with `sorted` so that's why I'm doing the bubble sort. But previously when I have overridden methods like `len` I didn't have to add another parameter and for sorted, how would it work? I'm pretty sure I can't do `self[i].publication_date`. Every time I run the code I get the following error, `'<' not supported between instances of 'Article' and 'Article'` why doesn't my code address that error?

```
import datetime


class Article():
    def __init__(self, title: str, author: str, publication_date: datetime.datetime, content: str):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.publication_date = publication_date
        self.content = content

    def __sorted__(self, x):
        print(x)
        for passnum in range(len(x)-1, 0, -1):
            for i in range(passnum):
                if x[i].publication_date > x[i+1].publication_date:
                    temp = x[i].publication_date
                    x[i].publication_date = x[i+1].publication_date
                    x[i+1].publication_date = temp
        print(x)
        return x


kwargs = {"title": "a", "author": "b", "content": "c"}
articles = [
    Article(
        **kwargs, publication_date=datetime.datetime(2001, 7, 5)),
    Article(
        **kwargs, publication_date=datetime.datetime(1837, 4, 7)),
    Article(
        **kwargs, publication_date=datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 20)),
    Article(
        **kwargs, publication_date=datetime.datetime(1837, 4, 7)),
]
print(articles[1].publication_date)  # prints 1837-04-07 00:00:00
print(sorted(articles))
```

Comment: Where did you get the impression that `__sorted__` was a special method that would be used? It isn't, at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement the `__lt__` method only for sorts to work correctly with developer-defined objects.

In this case, your code should become:

```
import datetime

class Article(object):
    def __init__(self, title: str, author: str, publication_date: datetime.datetime, content: str):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.publication_date = publication_date
        self.content = content

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.publication_date < other.publication_date
```

If you want to compare based on more attributes than just publication date, you'll need to add that logic in `__lt__`.

Answer (score 0):

Using [dataclasses](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-classes-in-python-an-introduction/amp/)

```
import datetime
import dataclasses #pip install dataclasses


@dataclasses.dataclass
class Article:
    title: str
    author: str
    pub_date: datetime.datetime
    content: str
    
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.pub_date < other.pub_date
    
kwargs = {"title": "a", "author": "b", "content": "c"}
articles = [
    Article(
        **kwargs, pub_date=datetime.datetime(2001, 7, 5)),
    Article(
        **kwargs, pub_date=datetime.datetime(1837, 4, 7)),
    Article(
        **kwargs, pub_date=datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 20)),
    Article(
        **kwargs, pub_date=datetime.datetime(1837, 4, 7)),
]
print(articles[1].pub_date)
print(sorted(articles))
```

gives,

```
1837-04-07 00:00:00
[Article(title='a', author='b', pub_date=datetime.datetime(1837, 4, 7, 0, 0), content='c'), Article(title='a', author='b', pub_date=datetime.datetime(1837, 4, 7, 0, 0), content='c'), Article(title='a', author='b', pub_date=datetime.datetime(2001, 7, 5, 0, 0), content='c'), Article(title='a', author='b', pub_date=datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 20, 0, 0), content='c')]

[Program finished]
```